# Encoding error in opening the links in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the follwoing code to make text clickable in android text.setText("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ii2FHbtVJzc");
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"

I am not able to open the link because the above link opens as http://www.youtube.com/E2%80%bwatch?v=Ii2FHbtVJzc in the browser

%80% are extra characters .

Comment: Are you sure the link you posted is correct? It does not open up in the browser. Post the correct link that appears so that we can understand.

Comment: Hm, that looks like `Left-to-right` UTF-8 mark. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark 
Now I wonder how it ended up there.